# Python: iterate through lines after reverse reading a text file

Tags: python, loops, lines

I am using Python 3.4.

I have a log file like this:

```
10001 ...
10002 * SMTP *
10003 skip me
10004 read me
10005 read me
```

The goal of the script is to open the file in reverse mode, and iterate through lines untill I found '* SMTP *' in it (in the example is line 10002), then I have to go back and skip a line and read the next 2 lines (in the example lines 10004 and 10005).

How can I do that?

Comment: why you want yo open the file in reverse mode?

Comment: because it is a huge file and we need only the last data starting from the end.

Comment: "I can I do that " Most likely. You will have to put in a little effort though.

Comment: you can reverse a python list with:
reversed(mylist)

Comment: Take a look at `file.seek` and `file.truncate`.

Comment: You can firstly truncate that file use `tail -n 5555 large_file > target_file` to get a smaller file. Here `5555` can be any number of lines you prefer to truncate from the large_file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) is a good way to go:

```
import mmap

SEARCH_TEXT = b'* SMTP *'
SKIP_LINES = 2
KEEP_LINES = 2

with open('log.txt', 'rb') as f:
    log = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
    n = log.rfind(SEARCH_TEXT)
    if n == -1:
        print('{!r} not found'.format(SEARCH_TEXT))
    else:
        log.seek(n)
        for i in range(SKIP_LINES):
            _ = log.readline()

        print(''.join(log.readline().decode() for _ in range(KEEP_LINES)))
```

**Output**

```
10004 read me
10005 read me
```

This code mmaps the log file, searches from the end of the file with `rfind()` for the target string `'* SMTP *'`. Then it positions the file pointer at the target string (using `seek()`), consumes the 2 unwanted lines, and finally reads the 2 lines of interest.

`mmap` is efficient because the OS handles paging of data from the disk into memory for your application. It does not read the whole file, so it is a good strategy for large files.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open (file) as textfile:
    lines = textfile.read().split("\n")
    lines.reverse()
    if lines.index("* SMTP *"):
        Ind =  int(lines.index("* SMTP *"))
        print lines[Ind-2]
        print lines[Ind-3]
        break
```

this will only find the latest occurance of * SMTP * in your log file and it is dirty, but gets the job done.

did some testing to compare @mhawke mmap vs mine. Testing is done on a 150k line test file.

**mmap**

```
real 0m0.024s
user 0m0.016s
sys  0m0.008s
```

**my solution**

```
real 0m0.038s
user 0m0.026s
sys  0m0.012s
```

Comment: this reads the whole file into memory and then manipulates it. This is going to be very slow with large files, and will be limited by available memory. With mmap the OS reads only the required pages into memory, and no manipulation of the data is required. The performance gap will widen as the file size increases.

Comment: yea I did some more testing with a 10m line file, and it did take my solution around 25/100th second while yours stayed at around 1/100th of a second. Your solution is definitely better.